# How to create styling library for React and Angular apps

Tags: css, reactjs, angular, npm, sass

I am creating a npm library that I will import into two different apps, one built in Angular andone built in React. The only purpose of the library is to define scss styles that I will be able to use in both apps. Since react requires styles be exported and imported i.e.

```
:export {
    color: $color;
    primary-color: $primaryColor;
}
```

What are best practices for structuring my files? Do I have to redefine styles so that they can be used properly by each of the apps? Currently, I cannot use any of the variables in my react app.

Here is what my library looks like so far:

```
Scss
    -common.scss  (where most of the variables used and turned into class styles)
          .common-blue {
             color: mat-color($primary-palette, 300);
           }
    -theming.scss (where most of the variables are declared)i.e.
          $primary-color: (
             50: #e0eff6,
             100: #b3d7e7
          )
main.scss (which contains)
     @import './scss/brand-styles.scss';
     @import './scss/theming.scss';
-package.json
-README.md
```

How can I redefine/restructure anything to

1. work in both react and angular
2. Be up to conventional standards

Thanks